# How to filter search data from mysql database and show it in the datatable?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, mysqli

I am using datatable to display data. I have large database nearly 15k rows and it takes times to load data so I am displaying only 200 rows in datatable. But search filter in the datatable are most important thing needed here. Therefore I need to search data directly from database by php through ajax call on keyup event. So how can i do that ?

This is what I have done till here.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Trail 2</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="datatable/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

    <style>
        tfoot input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 3px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <br><br>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Surname</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>Mobile No</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Search by NAME"></th>
                            <th>Surname</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>Mobile No</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php 
                    require('connectivity2.php');

                    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM member LIMIT 200;";
                    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
                        $name = $row['m_name'];
                        $surname = $row['m_sec_surname'];
                        $city = $row['m_city'];
                        $no = $row['m_mobile'];
                    ?>  
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $surname; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $city; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                <?php   }  //End of while loop
                ?>      
                    </tbody>    
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="datatable/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            // DataTable
            var table = $('#example').DataTable();

            // Search
            $("#name").keyup(function(){
                var m_name = $("input[name='name']").val();
                //window.alert(m_name);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'trial2php.php',
                    data: {member name:m_name},
                    cache: true,
                    datatype: 'html',
                    success: function(){
                        $('#example').DataTable();
                    }
                });
            });

        } );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here I have taken just one input text in footer of the table for testing search.

Something is wrong in ajax function. Please help me out here.

Comment: Using jQuery/AJAX isn't a magic bullet that's going to affect how long it takes for your query to run. What you need to do is break the data down in to chunks which can be served to the UI in batches of a manageable size, 100 records per request for example. To do that, use paging, filtering or a combination of both

Comment: Dont print everything into the table, it would be a memory hog for the browser as well. Query your database directly with Ajax as you suggested and use the `LIMIT` statement and update the table. Ajax is nothing more then a POST to a PHP file initiated by JS, query the database with the values and parse the echo'd value in javascript and place it where it needs to go.

Comment: Since you are using datatables, you shouldn't be fetching all 15k records at once. You should rather use 'limit' and add a pagination that comes with datatables. That would be faster, and quicker to implement too. Ajax or JQuery isn't going to affect the speed of MySQL. It's completely unrelated.

Comment: First of all lose this `$query1 = "SELECT * FROM itemtable;";`  select what you need

Comment: Okay so now i have limited my data with 200 rows in datatable. But I want search filter to search data from mysql table and show the result on the same datatable. Can you give any idea about how do i refresh datatable with  new results without load and on keydown @Xorifelse

Answer (score 0):

**Select only needed columns:**

```
SELECT ItemCode, ItemName, RackNo, ItemSrNo
```

**Create indexes for columns:**

```
ItemCode, ItemName, RackNo, ItemSrNo
```

See:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

Comment: Oh, wouw, I have about 3.7 million rows in my DB. Is this the magic bullet I've been waiting for?

Comment: Then you should really use also LIMIT 15000;

Comment: And my Galaxy S3 would not crash due an out of memory issue showing 15k rows of data? Incase you didn't get my first statement, it was meant sarcasticly. This is not the way to do things, there is never a need to show 15k results. Not even 1k, 500, or even 250. Perhaps 50 or 100 using pagination.

Comment: @Xorifelse great answer but If there is need then what is solution becuase some one has asked question in interview

Comment: simple, your `keyup` event should post the data to a PHP script using js `$.post` and use that value to query your `"title"` column with a ` %wildcard%` value, using `LIMIT` you echo the data in [tag:JSON] and update your table with the new values. Basic ajax example. But I'm quite sure DataTables has a simplified feature for that as well, however I am not very knowledgeable in DataTables so I suggest your scour their API.

Answer (score 0):

You should use *Server Side processing with Pipeline* feature of DataTables. This way fetching, rendering and filtering data in DataTables will be smooth.

Follow the link below to know more about the process with example -

[DataTables Server Side Processing with Pipeline](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/pipeline.html)